# How do I add animation to this jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I would like to add some animation to this jquery, at the moment the div 'pops up' on hover.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.recruiterLink').hover(function() {

    $(this).css({
        'bottom' : 0
    });

}, function() {

    $(this).css({
        'bottom' : -20
    });

});

});
```

How do I go about doing that? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this (should work out of the box)?

```
$('.recruiterLink').hover(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        'bottom': '0px'
    }, 500);
}, function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        'bottom': '-20px'
    }, 500);
});
```

This will animate the `bottom` CSS property for 500 ms. It also aborts all running animations to prevent awkward behaviour (caused by queueing).

Comment: This is the best solution Anthony, I was writing exactly the same, +1.

Answer (score 1):

just change the `.css` to `.animate`

Something like the following would work:

```
$('.recruiterLink').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({bottom : 0},1000);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop(false,false).animate({bottom: -20},1000);
});
```

I've added the stop function in the hover off so that if the previous animation hasn't finished it finishes straight away.

Comment: A 0 ms animation is not really useful, is it?

Comment: Sorry hadn't finished writing.

Comment: @elusive before downvoting you should know that animate() has a default duration of 400ms...

Comment: @fcalderan: I did not downvote, but thanks for that bit of information :)

Answer (score 1):

replace `.css()` function

with, for example

```
.stop().animate({ bottom:'-=20px' },"slow")
```

for JQuery animate() API reference:
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

just change `.css()` with `.animate()`

Comment: Need to specify speed as well. Is not weel explained.

Comment: This is the simplest solution to my problem, however adding in .stop() is also a good idea.

Comment: @toro: there's no need to specify a duration, is not a mandatory attribute since 400ms is the default speed. the suggestion works anyway. ;)

Comment: yes but is not a good example, without the stop(), without the speed, if someone need to learn how "animate()" work, the example provided by Elusive is much better. TBH.